# return outside the function

Tags: python-3.x, string, substring

there is a syntax error that says that i am returning outside the function

I tried all the possible solutions that people used on the same problem with there code and i still get the same error

the error is in line 32 in the line return result

Problem Introduction
In this problem, we ask a simple question: how many times one string occurs as a substring of another? Recall that di erent occurrences of a substring can overlap with each other. For example, ATA occurs three times in CGATATATCCATAG.

Problem Description
Task. Find all occurrences of a pattern in a string.

Input Format. Strings  and .

Constraints. 1 ≤ || ≤ 106; 1 ≤ || ≤ 106; both strings are over A, C, G, T.

Sample 1.
Input:
Output:
1 12
4 1.5 2
4 4 24
  TACG GT
 Explanation:
The pattern is longer than the text and hence has no occurrences in the text.
Sample 2.
Input:
Output:
02
Explanation:
The pattern appears at positions 1 and 3 (and these two occurrences overlap each other).
Sample 3.
Input:
Output:
139
Explanation:
The pattern appears at positions 1, 3, and 9 in the text.
 ATA ATATA
 ATAT
GATATATGCATATACTT

```
# python3
import sys


 def compute_prefix_function(pattern):
s = [0] * len(pattern)
border = 0

  for i in range(1, len(pattern)):
    while (border > 0) and (pattern[i] != pattern[border]):
        border = s[border - 1]
    if pattern[i] == pattern[border]:
        border = border + 1
    else:
        border = 0
    s[i] = border

return s


def find_pattern(pattern, text):
S = pattern + '$' + text
s = compute_prefix_function(S)
result = []

p = len(pattern)

for i in range(p + 1, len(S)):
    if s[i] == p:
        result.append(i - 2 * p)


 return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

pattern = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

text = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

 result = find_pattern(pattern, text)

 print(" ".join(map(str, result)))
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. As the error says,  `return` can only be inside a function

Comment: Indentation is a crucial thing in Python, not just esthetic like `C` for example. A function's scope is defined by everything indented under the `def` statement. Your indentations all over are wrong so you will probably get more errors. Everything after a line ending in `:` should be indented

Answer (score 0):

Realize that white space/indentation matters in python, and replaces the { }, used in most other language to define a scope. Something like this is a proper function (although, the return isn't really necessary):

```
def foo():
    print("bar")
    return
```

Doing this instead would result in an error message similar to your, though, because the return now is outside the scope of the function:

```
def foo():
    print("bar")
return
```

For more info just Google for [python indentation tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20indentation%20tutorial).

Comment: Just a side note - you really don't have to reinvent the wheel just to count how many times a substring appears in a string, just use length of the re.findall, and don't forget to re.escape the substring.